# Get the Url for a content item from within an ApiController in Orchard

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, orchardcms

Is there a way for a the display Url for a certain content item in an ApiController? In a regular MVC Controller I can do

```
Url.ItemDisplayUrl(item)
```

I want to be able to do something similar from an ApiController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an instance of `System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper` (the type of the `Url` property in a regular MVC controller) using

```
var myUrlHelper = new System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext);
```

If you add `using Orchard.Mvc.Html;` to the top, you can do

```
myUrlHelper.ItemDisplayUrl(item);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at [ContentItemExtensions](https://orchard.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Orchard/Mvc/Html/ContentItemExtensions.cs) you will see that the url is retrieved from the metadata. If you're using AutoroutePart you can get it from there too.